# Round all Float Value in a PHP Page

Tags: php, math

There's a method to Round all floats in the output of a PHP script?

For example:

```
$var_float1 = 585.584826684587;
$var_float2 = 675.457567845657;
$var_float3 = 123.9058021466589;
echo $var_float1;
echo $var_float2;
echo $var_float3;
```

I want all float output rounded, without use Round() function each time, like a setting of the page

Comment: Could you not store the floats in a data structure like an array and use a loop?

Comment: Is it to avoid typing in `8` each time or is it to ensure that you're always rounding to 8 places? If it's the latter just assign a variable `$iRoundToPlaces = 8;` then `round(3.14159265359, $iRoundToPlaces);` ... however, if it's the former then are you just being lazy? :P

Comment: yes, i'm a lot lazy... so... i have a lots of float... and i can't do it foer each :\

Comment: i have edit the post ;)

Comment: i have edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom function:

```
function round8($input){
    $output = round($input, 8);
    return $output; 
}
$better = round8(585.8958448484);
echo $better;
```

Comment: ... i want to do it in all of the page

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you posted some code. Are your floats stored in an array at any point?

Comment: So are threads of cotton in another context. Specifics, please. Post some code. There probably is a way to automate it, but I can't help if I can't see where you're starting and where you're trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use round() ?

```
$x = round(3.141592, 3);
echo $x; // outputs 3.142
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

**Update**

And if you want to do this for more floats.

```
$arr = [3.1415, 346.78454, 346.255];

foreach($arr as $f) 
{
    echo round($f, 3);
}
```

Comment: @carbos is aware of `round()` as stated in his question.

Comment: He may be aware, but the question doesn't provide much to help with. My answer I think satisfies at least what I think he is asking for.

Comment: I have a string with a lots of float.. i can't use round for each...

Answer (score 0):

No, a float has no concept of how it will be represented, it's just a number (kudos for trying to reduce code though!). You have to tell it how it will be represented.

If you want to display the number then you'll have to, at some point call `round()` or `number_format` on it. Whether that is through a custom function or a loop (as other answerers mentioned) is up to you.